# Laravel temporary blank white page without error for some users

Tags: php-7.2, laravel-6.2

After website deployment  to sharing host  , sometimes the all routed o websites is becomes white page, but at the same time and on the same system on another browser, the entire website routes comes up and works properly.

white page accures for 1 minute or short time and then it's gone.
I mean if all website be come white page for me in my laptop I can access it on my mobile at same time. And after 1 minute blank page I'd gone for me! This blank page is not permanent.

This condition may be reversed after a few minutes and crash on the correct browser and be fixed on another one.

There are no errors in Laravel and the server Log, whether based on Memory Limited or other things, Laravel can write errors because normal errors are stored in Laravel Error Log, but I did not see any error that explains this White Page.

And this problem does not exist when one user is working with the site, but when there are More than One user, this error occurs for some of them and after some minutes it's gone !!!

This is my website details:

```
"laravel/framework": "^6.2"// v6.20.30 "php": "^7.2",

and local server php version is 7.2

then share hosting php version is 7.3
```

Even when I turn on the debug mode, the screen is still white and no error is displayed

I tried:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
-php artisan optimize
-composer update
```

And blank page source code is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>ŁŁŲÆŲ¬Ł</title>

</body>
</html>
```

And storage folder and cache folder in bootstrap folder permisson is 777.
But no luck

Server LAST ERROR LOGS IS:

```
[Tue Oct  5 08:52:18 2021] [error] [client 162.244.52.124] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403, [Rule: 'TX:EXTENSION' '!@pmFromFile userdata_wl_extensions'] [id "210730"] [rev "4"] [msg "COMODO WAF: URL file extension is restricted by policy"] [logdata ".com/"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "HTTP"]

2021-10-05 11:24:15.715022 [WARN] [804] [79.175.138.132:46644#APVH_www..mysite.com:443] Request has not been logged into access log, response body sent: 146959!
```

And Laravel Error Logs is :

```
#6 /home/MySite/domains/MySite.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\UserArea\StudentController), 'student_join_me...')
#7 /home/MySite/domains/MySite.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#8 /home/MySite/domains/MySite.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()

#30 /home/MySite/domains/MySite.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

If you have any feedback, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line from the server error logs you provided is a ModSecurity log line. We can see that the Comodo WAF is in use:

```
[msg "COMODO WAF: URL file extension is restricted by policy"]
[logdata ".com/"]
```

It looks like a request is being made to a location that ends in ".com". This is triggering a rule on the Comodo WAF and so the request is being blocked. If the blocked request is important to the web application you're trying to use then it may be the cause of your issue.

**Try disabling your Comodo WAF and then re-testing your application.**

If disabling the WAF solves your problem then you should look into implementing a proper fix for your WAF. (Try searching for something like 'Comodo WAF rule exclusion', 'Comodo WAF tuning', or 'Comodo WAF false positives'.)

Comment: Thanks it was WAF Problem, this made me to change my sharing host to server for my WebSite